# How should I start this test in JEST?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I have this piece of code that I need to test:

```
const opportunityId = request.answers.find(
  (answer) => answer.questionNumber === MobilizeQuestionsNumbers.OpportunityId
)?.value;

const riskRating = request.answers.find(
  (answer) => answer.questionNumber === MobilizeQuestionsNumbers.RiskRating
)?.value;

if (opportunityId) {
  const opportunity = await this.opportunityModel.getOpportunityBySapIdFromPSql(
    Number(opportunityId)
  );
  if (opportunity && riskRating) {
    const index = request.answers.findIndex(
      (answer) => answer.questionNumber === MobilizeQuestionsNumbers.OpportunityId
    );
    request.answers[index].value = null;
    contract.opportunityPkey = opportunity.id;
  } else {
    contract.opportunityPkey = null;
  }
  await this.contractsModel.update(contract, {
    where: {
      id: contract.id,
    },
  });
}`
```

And I don't know hot to start to test the first If and the others Ifs inside? I made this to start:

```
it('should upsert an answer when the opportunity exist', async () => {
  const request: PutMobilizeAnswerRequest = {
    contractId: 1,
    answers: [
      {
        mobilizeQuestionId: 1,
        questionNumber: '1.1',
        value: 'yes',
      },
      {
        mobilizeQuestionId: 13,
        questionNumber: '3.1',
        value: 123456,
      },
      {
        mobilizeQuestionId: 13,
        questionNumber: '3.12',
        value: 123456,
      },
    ],
  };
});
```

but I don't know how to continue...Thanks.

Comment: You can't test bare code like that. How is that code reached? Is it part of a method? What is the relationship between your `request` and the code?

Comment: But that is the only part that I changed...

Comment: The test isn't magic. It has to execute that code the same way any other program would. Probably by calling a method. For example, it looks like that code handles a request, so the test has to make a request. We can't tell you how to make a request of your own code.

Comment: Is there any page, video or book that I could read so I can understand how to do a test like this? I mean, with two if, a loop inside, something like that.

Comment: There is not enough information to understand what you're trying to test. You've only shown us a fragment of code with no context and no way to run the code. The test has to run the code. How would you normally run that code? It must live inside a method. We must know how to call that method, what arguments it takes, what it returns, and what side effects it has. Without that information, we can't help you test it or even point you at other help beyond a generic Jest tutorial.